# Maximal subgroups of $PSL(2,q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

Let $q = p^n$ be any prime power. It is possible to list all subgroups of $G = PSL(2,q)$. This is done for example in [Huppert - Endliche Gruppen]. However, the proof is quite long, and I am only interested in listing the maximal subgroups of $G$ - e.g. to convince myself that there is no nontrivial transitive group action of $G$ on less than $q+1$ elements if $q > 11$.

Does anybody know a reference, where only the maximal subgroups of $G$ are derived? Alternatively, can the standard proof of listing all subgroups somehow be shortened if only maximal subgroups are considered?

---

**Possible Attempt:** Since $G$ operates primitive on the projective line, the one point stabilzers are maximal subgroups (they are semidirect products of an elementary abelian $p$-group and a cyclic group). Hence, these are precisely the maximal subgroups with at least one fixed point, all other maximal subgroups are fixed-point-free. Maybe this information can be used to shorten the standard proof.

Comment: Some information (at least for many prime powers up to $241$) can be found in the [ATLAS of Finite Group Representations](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/)

Comment: @jpvee: Thanks! But my question is not about the list itself (which has been found for arbitrary q), but about a (preferably short) proof.

Comment: I don't beleive that  finding the maximal subgroups is any easier than finding all subgroups.  In both cases,the trickiest to find are $A_4$, $S_4$ and $A_5$.